# RPM - manage dependencies of dependencies

Tags: java, ant, packaging, rpm

I have a java application that I'm packaging up as an RPM, which had been working well for a while, until I pushed out an updated java-1.7.0-oracle-devel package.

The spec file used to build my java-1.7.0-oracle-devel package is loosely based on: https://github.com/puzzle/java-oracle-rpm/blob/master/java-1.7.0-oracle-devel.spec, which manages 'alternatives' but doesn't have a conflict statement with other versions of java.

The requirements of the app are:

- The package must be compiled with ant, using java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
- The compiled package must run under java-1.7.0-oracle-devel

The ant package I'm using (specified via BuildRequires) is the standard CentOS package from the base repo, and this Requires java-devel >= 0:1.5.0. Both java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel and java-1.7.0-oracle-devel provide java-devel, so therefore it is grabbing the latest package that provides this.

I've tried specifying java-devel within the spec file that it needs less that java-devel 1.7.0, but this didn't work - the build process still pulled in both java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel and java-1.7.0-oracle-devel (as a dependency of ant).

```
BuildRequires:  java-devel >= 1.6.0
BuildRequires:  java-devel < 1.7.0
```

I have a workaround here in that as I'm using mock I can simply disable the repo containing java-1.7.0-oracle-devel, but I'd like to be able to achieve this within the RPM spec if possible: I'd like to be able to state that 'java-devel' is provided by java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.

Do RPM specs have the capability to manage dependencies of dependencies in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe RPM is capable of encoding a requirement like that (of multiple parts).

I believe you have two choices. Either specify a version specifically (i.e. `BuildRequires: java-devel = 1.6.0`) or drop the minimum version specification (since you are assuming that will be satisfied in your environment) and include only the `BuildRequires: java-devel < 1.7.0` entry.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question here :)

Specifying greater than X but less than Y as above works fine for the package being built, but the issue is managing a dependency of a build dependency (in this case the ant package), which has java-devel > 1.5.0, and so as a dependent of that it will pull in the latest package that provides java-devel.

From doing more research into the subject I think that this functionality could be provided by a filter:  http://rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/DependencyGenerator

Haven't yet managed to get it working yet though :(

Comment: @rdark Are you sure the dual `BuildRequires` is actually working correctly? I really don't think rpm can actually handle that (it might be being interpreted as just the "less than" prereq like I suggested and so "working" correctly (you'd have to forge a `java-devel = 1.4.0` providing package as the sole provider to really test that I think). You can't do anything to the dependency of a `BuildRequires` dependency, the best you can do is augment the requirements of that package with your package's `BuildRequires` so that you assert what you need as well.

Comment: @rdark Generators are for automating the detection of dependencies of built packages from the contents of files. The way the perl/python/etc. dependency generators handle module dependency detection I believe. They can't help with `BuildRequires` that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yeah - dual `BuildRequires` works perfectly (as described for `Requires` here> http://serverfault.com/a/411506)  - I have both java-1.6.0-openjdk and java-1.7.0-openjdk available, and it correctly selects java-1.6.0-openjdk.
java-1.7.0-oracle-devel is being pulled in by ant.

Comment: @rdark Having both `1.6.0` and `1.7.0` and selecting `1.6.0` is perfectly compatible with it not working and only having used the `java-devel < 1.7.0` requires entry. You cannot, from this alone, assert that both tests are working (hence my `1.4.0` comment before). You can't control what other packages on the system have *already* pulled in. You can control what gets pulled in when your requirements *and* another package's requirements are being satisfied at the same time. If your requirements are already unmet but the other packages are met yum will not fix that for you (by downgrading).